# How to mimic the amplitude of an instrument's sound waves?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

for a homework project, I'm meant to imitate the sound waves of an instrument. The sound wave is calculated with the following formula, A = amplitude * sin(2 * pi * frequency * t) with t being time. I'm lost as to how I can manipulate the amplitude (it can be a function on its own) to get the sound of a piano, though it doesn't need to be a piano.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

What class is this "homework" for?  Or is this just something you find interesting.  I will assume the latter.

You will not get very far modeling an entire instrument with a single wave function.  But here is a start.

The equation you posted has two free parameters, amplitude and frequency.  The amplitude is related to the volume of sound and the frequency the pitch.  You can adjust both to match you expectations, or data.

If you need to model the loudness of the sound at different distances away from the instrument than a very simple model would be the inverse distance law.  The amplitude of the sound (pressure wave) would decrease with distance by 1/R, where R is the distance from the instrument to the listener.  This assumes that the instrument is a point and projects sound equally in all direction.  The intensity would scale as 1/R^2.

If you really want to model the sound coming from a musical instrument in a way that is realistic, that synthesizes the true sound, then there is a lot more work that needs to be done.

Real instruments produce not just one frequency per note played but a whole series of harmonics, or overtones.  For simple models of strings and standing waves in a pipe (like a sax or other brass/woodwind instruments) the harmonics are all related to the fundamental tone by, fn = n * f1, where f1 is the note being played.

The number and amount of each harmonic present is related to how the vibrations of the instrument are set in motion, the attack.  For this you are missing a free parameter in your wave, the phase.

A = amplitude * sin(2 * pi * frequency * t + phase).

The sound from a real instrument is then written as

A = sum(a_n * sin(2 * pi * f_n * t + phase_n), over all n = 1 to infinity).

There is a mathematical procedure for getting the a_n, and phase_n for each harmonic called a Fourier transform.

In addition to this the sound from real instruments decays in time, it doesn't last forever.  This is modeled in the equations using a factor exp(-g_n * t) for each mode where g_n is a damping factor, different for each mode.  These can be figured out from the original wave equation used to determine the vibrations.

So, all of that is needed to get a realistic model of "sound wave of an instrument".

If you could add some more explanation to your question we could provide more help.